# Junit test cases for private reference and maps

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to learn junit testing and mockito. I would like to know how to write test cases if there are Maps and private method reference.

```
@Autowired
AppProps props;

public Foo checkStatus(){
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     foo.setStatus("Up");
     
     Map<String,List<String>> childStatusList = getChildStatus();
     foo.setChildStatus(childStatusList);

     return foo;
}

private Map<String,List<String>> getChildStatus(){
    Map<String,List<String>> healthMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

    String url = "https://google.com";
    for(Entry<Integer,List<String>> entrySet: props.getMap().entrySet()){ 
        for(String str : entrySet.getValue()){
             healthMap.put("Up", Arrays.asList(url));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). I downvoted because 
[No research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 1):

The first and most important thing you have to learn about *Unit Tests* is:

> Unit Test do **not** test code.
> Unit Test verify *public observable behavior* which is *return values* and *communication with dependencies*.

Any attempt to use <strike>Jailbreak</strike> or <strike>PowerMock</strike> is just a surrender to bad design decisions.